# What does the slope of a rotational Displacement Graph indicate?

Tags: physics

If you have a graph of the displacement vs time of an object in angular/rotational motion, what would the slope of the graph indicate conceptually?

Comment: Velocity in the y direction.

Comment: angular velocity